# Run Flask application with Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: python, web-applications, nginx, flask, gunicorn

it is the first time that I deploy a webapp and I really need of your help.
I want to run a Flask web app on a server using Nginx and Gunicorn. I found [this](http://www.onurguzel.com/how-to-run-flask-applications-with-nginx-using-gunicorn/) tutorial but I can not to run the application correctly. I tried also other ways found in internet, but nothing.
This is my current /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf file

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name hello.itu24.com;

root /home/ubuntu/test;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;    
    }
}
```

Instead this is my app /home/ubuntu/test.py

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return "Hello world!"

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then I run the following command

```
ubuntu@ace:~$ sudo service nginx reload
* Reloading nginx configuration nginx                           [ OK ] 
ubuntu@ace:~$ sudo gunicorn -b h 127.0.0.1:8000 test:app
```

Then if I go to IP address of the machine, since I am connecting from another machine, I can see the Nginx page. But if I add the port in the address IP:8000 no page is found. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx probably has another site defaulting to port 80. Make sure you've deleted the default.conf symlink from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. Check the nginx.conf to make sure it doesn't have a server configured in it.

Your gunicorn command doesn't look quite right either. You need to use `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 test:app` from your app's directory.

Comment: Great, now it works! Sorry, but I read no where that default configuration had to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the gunicorn server only to the local interface 127.0.0.1, so it is not available from outside. You have to use nginx as the reverse proxy at port 80.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it, please?

Comment: I made these changes in the configuration file.
`root /home/ubuntu;` and `proxy_pass http://SERVER_IP:8000;`
Are they correct?
I lunch the application in this way `sudo service nginx reload` and then `gunicorn -b h 127.0.0.1:8000 test:app`. Finally I go to the page SERVER_IP:8000. Is it right? Because still it does not work. Forgive me, but I am a beginner.

Comment: I see the welcome page of Nginx instead of the webapp. The gunicorn command is correct? I found that I should use `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 test:app` to allow connections from outside. Is this command in charge of running the webapp? Because I am not running python test.py.